# How to return the equivalent of a VB6 Variant type from a method in C#

Tags: c#, vb6, variant

I have an older VB6 app that has a function RunReturningVAR it is a db call that could return an `int`, `string`, `double`..... but not a `RecordSet`. It was built very generically so that it can be called by multiple other functions so we don't have multiple locations for DB calls. 
what I currently have is attached.

```
Public Function RunReturningVar(ByVal vstrSql As String, _
Optional ByVal connval As Boolean = False, _
Optional ByVal copyID As Double = 0, _
Optional ByVal corpVal As Boolean = False, _
Optional ByVal vintConnectionTimeout As Integer = 30) As Variant
```

Comment: Nothing is attached, but you could return an `object`, which is a variant.

Comment: sorry, it is now in my question

Comment: Why, oh why, is this tagged c#?

Comment: @rory.ap I guess he wants to rewrite it in c#

Comment: @rory.ap did you even read the question?

Comment: @Hackerman -- Ctrl + F in your browser.  I only find one -- in the title, which seems like a mistake/confusion since the rest of the question is about VB and doesn't mention C# anywhere.

Comment: @rory.ap Yes, they only said *once* that they're trying to write the VB code into C#.  Why would they need to say it more than once?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

VB6 [`Variant`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa261347(v=vs.60)) (Can't believe I've found that link!) translates c# [`dynamic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic).

```
public dynamic RunReturningVar(
    string vstrSql, 
    bool connval = false,
    double copyID = 0,
    bool corpVal = false,
    int vintConnectionTimeout = 30) 
{
    // do your stuff here 
}
```

It almost translates to `object`, but `Variant` is a data type specific for 
late-binding, and it can hold reference types and value types - unlike c# `object` that can hold value types only through boxing.

Please note that working with `dynamic` means you bypass all the compile time type checks, which can result with run time errors you wouldn't normally expect from a c# program.

Perhaps you could do better with generics, but that would require you to specify the return type from the calling method:

```
public T RunReturningVar<T>(
    string vstrSql, 
    bool connval = false,
    double copyID = 0,
    bool corpVal = false,
    int vintConnectionTimeout = 30) where T : new()
{
    // do your stuff here and return T
}
```

Also, For a public method in a public class, I would **strongly suggest against using optional parameters** in c#.
Use method overloading to specify default values.
The reason for that is the way optional parameters works in c#:
When a method with an optional parameter is being called, and the optional parameter is omitted, it's default value gets compiled into the method call.
So if you call to this method from another assembly, omitting some of the optional parameters - like this:

```
yourObjectReference.RunReturningVar(sql, true);
```

The c# compiler actually translate that to:

```
yourObjectReference.RunReturningVar(sql, true, 0, false, 30);
```

This means that if you ever want to change the default value of any of the parameters, other assemblies referencing this one should also be recompiled.
Therefor, a better alternative is to use method overloading:

```
public dynamic RunReturningVar(
    string vstrSql, 
    bool connval,
    double copyID,
    bool corpVal,
    int vintConnectionTimeout) 
{
    // do your stuff here 
}

public dynamic RunReturningVar(
    string vstrSql, 
    bool connval,
    double copyID,
    bool corpVal
    ) 
{
    return RunReturningVar(vstrSql, connval, copyID, corpVal, 30);
}

public dynamic RunReturningVar(
    string vstrSql, 
    bool connval,
    double copyID,
    ) 
{
    return RunReturningVar(vstrSql, connval, copyID, false);
}
```

and so on.

Comment: That's very interesting about how C# handles optional parameters

Comment: Dear downvoter: Can you please leave a comment specifying what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: wow, Thank you very much for the info on the optional. I had no clue.

Comment: @LeeHopkins I think a lot of developers doesn't know that. I had no idea about it in the first year I've been using c#, and it's only by pure chance I've seen it explained on stackoverflow (can't remember where, though, that was a long time ago). So I kinda feel like more people should know that and if I answer a question regarding code that has optional parameters I do mention that (most of the time, more briefly, though)