# VB DLL Variant() to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba, dll

I have a working Excel file(with VB code) which uses DLL library.
The original VB code is as follows:

```
Dim Inputs() As Double
Dim Outputs() As Variant
ReDim Inputs(1 To 1, 1 To NbrInputs&)
For i& = 1 To NbrInputs&
Inputs(1, i&) = CDbl(InRange(i&).Value)
Next i&

ABC.CalculateMatrix(Inputs#, Outputs)
```

The corresponding C# code:

```
Array Inputs = Array.CreateInstance(
    typeof(double), 
    new[] { 1, NbrInputs },
    new[] { 1, 1 });        
for (int i = 1; i <= NbrInputs; i++)
{
    double value = Convert.ToDouble(InRange[i].Value);
    Inputs.SetValue(value, 1, i);
}


ABC.CalculateMatrix(Inputs, Outputs);
```

But there is a problem how to declare Outputs???
Following options didn't work

```
Object[] Outputs = new Object[1]; //Object variable or With block variable not set
System.Array Outputs = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(Object), 1);//cannot convert from 'ref object[]' to 'ref System.Array'

System.Array Outputs = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(Object), 1);//Object variable or With block variable not set
```

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated...

Declaring dynamic array doesn't help

```
dynamic[] Outputs = new dynamic[1]; //Object variable or With block variable not set
```

Comment: Try to use [`dynamic` to replace `variant`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49756545/how-to-return-the-equivalent-of-a-vb6-variant-type-from-a-method-in-c-sharp/49756671#49756671)

Comment: Changing to dynamic dynamic[] Outputs = new dynamic [1];   //Object variable or With block variable not set