# Can someone please explain (nicely) why OOP Method Overloading is a good thing?

Tags: c#, c++, methods

First, please no spamming because I am not necessarily an OOP devotee.  That said, I have been a programmer on and off for almost 30 years and have created a lot of pretty cool production code systems/solutions in several industries. I've also done my share of break/fix, database development, etc.  Even a bout 10 years as a web programmer, not developer, so I an not so much a newbie but someone trying to get an answer about something that frankly is eluding me.

I started as a "C" programmer int he early 1980's and "C" served me well into the early 2000s (even today most scripting and higher level languages use "C" syntactical elements).

That said, overloading seems to violate every principle of what I was taught were "good coding practices" by increasing ambiguity in the opportunity for omission of intended code to be executed for a given condition or actually running a routine you didn't expect to due to some condition falling through the cracks. Also generally seems to creates LOTS of confusion for learners.

I am not saying overloading is bad per se, I just want to better understand it's practical application to real problems other than simply a way to provide input validation or perhaps just to  handle inputs from other sources that you have no control over in an API or something else that you don't necessarily know the type of (again not clear on how or why that could actually happen either)  C# has a lot of parse and try catch to handle this as do most OOP languages.

In over a decade, I have yet to get a straight, non judgmental and dare I say unsnarky answer to this question. Surely there is someone who can offer a reasonable explanation of why it is used.

So I pose the question to you the stack overflow gurus, Personally, does having a method/function that is potentially callable multiple different ways with multiple exclusive code segments really a good thing, or does it just suggest lack of good planning when designing software.  Again, not knocking, judging, or disparaging, I just don't get it.....please enlighten me!

Comment: Don't ask this on StackOverflow. You could rather try it at SoftwareEngineering StackExchange

Comment: Overloading is not necessarily an OOP thing. Think of the new signature (including the parameters) as being part of the name of the function. So, it saves having to come up with redundant names like print_int, print_float etc. It also works nicely with templates.

Comment: This is a good question, bot unfortunately off-topic to stackoverflow. It's better suited, as Adrian wrote, to SoftwareEngineering.

Comment: If your overloads do completely different things, then yes, you missed the point of overloading. But if they do the same thing based on different types, see `std::to_string`, then no.

Comment: One good reason for method ovrerloading is to [avoid optional parameters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49756545/how-to-return-the-equivalent-of-a-vb6-variant-type-from-a-method-in-c-sharp/49756671#49756671) (the second part of the answer I've linked to)

Comment: About overloading -- with `C` -- `add_int(), add_double(), add_float(), add_long()`.  With C++, just `add()` and you provide the argument.  Which one looks more maintainable?

Comment: So you are telling that you've been enjoying typing entire function signature as part of  the function name (like `write_opt_float_arr`) for 25 years?

Comment: Also I don't see how overloading may "increasing ambiguity". Implicit conversions, crazy function lookup and overload resolution rules in c++ definitely may. But just overloading - hardly.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) is a pretty good example of good use of overloading. Why would you want to have different functions for converting different types to `std::string`? You don't. You just want one - `std::to_string` and you want it to behave sensibly whatever type of argument you give it - and it does just that. Using overloading keeps the client code simple.

Comment: You still have multiple functions, they just happen to have the same name.

Comment: @Theodoros Chatzigiannakis - true. But from rhe callers point of view there's just `to_string`.

Comment: And that is a good rationale Why?  I have never had a good answer to that question. And Not once without being ridiculed.  I started out as a "C" Systems analyst and Developer and have written Java, C#, and many other language based solutions.  Never understood why overloaded ANYTHING was a good practice. I can live with Objects, but the overload thing and potential for unexpected results negates any advantage to the hassle.